# Divider on Ionic lists not showing

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to replicate the sliding list as seen on the [Official Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#list-no-lines). The list shows up but there is no divider. The docs says that the divider/border shows by default, but it is not showing.

**This is the template:**

```
<ion-content padding>
 <ion-list>
  <ion-item-sliding>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="../assets/imgs/logo.png">
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>Slimer</h2>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options side="left">
      <button ion-button color="primary">
        <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
        Text
      </button>
      <button ion-button color="secondary">
        <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
        Call
      </button>
    </ion-item-options>
    <ion-item-options side="right">
      <button ion-button color="primary">
        <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>
        Email
      </button>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
<ion-list>
  <ion-item-sliding>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="../assets/imgs/logo.png">
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>Slimer</h2>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options side="left">
      <button ion-button color="primary">
        <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
        Text
      </button>
      <button ion-button color="secondary">
        <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
        Call
      </button>
    </ion-item-options>
    <ion-item-options side="right">
      <button ion-button color="primary">
        <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>
        Email
      </button>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
Hello DevApp!
</ion-content>
```

**This is what I get:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ion-list for each `ion-item-sliding`. May be this is a typo. All `ion-item-sliding` should have single parent `ion-list`

```html
<ion-content padding>
      <ion-list>
         <ion-item-sliding>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="../assets/imgs/logo.png">
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>Slimer</h2>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options side="left">
      <button ion-button color="primary">
        <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
        Text
      </button>
      <button ion-button color="secondary">
        <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
        Call
      </button>
    </ion-item-options>
    <ion-item-options side="right">
      <button ion-button color="primary">
        <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>
        Email
      </button>
    </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
    <!-- Remove these lines --> 
    <!-- </ion-list> -->
    <!-- <ion-list> -->
  <ion-item-sliding>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="../assets/imgs/logo.png">
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>Slimer</h2>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options side="left">
      <button ion-button color="primary">
        <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
        Text
      </button>
      <button ion-button color="secondary">
        <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
        Call
      </button>
    </ion-item-options>
    <ion-item-options side="right">
      <button ion-button color="primary">
        <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>
        Email
      </button>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
Hello DevApp!
</ion-content>
```

Comment: It is as you pointed out. All ion-item-sliding should have single parent ion-list.